# Repaint() method doesn't invoke paint() & paintComponent() methods one by one, only paintComponent () method is working

Tags: java, swing, repaint

My application can crop images. What I want to achieve is rectangle to be drawn before image is cut according to the coordinates taken from the MouseListeners.
This is my code:

```
public class ImageScreenShot extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    ImagePanel im;

    int drag_status = 0, c1, c2, c3, c4;

    public int getC1() {
        return c1;
    }

    public int getC2() {
        return c2;
    }

    public int getC3() {
        return c3;
    }

    public int getC4() {
        return c4;
    }

    public void cut() {
        im = new ImagePanel();
        GraphicalUserInterface.getFrame().add(im);
        im.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        im.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void draggedScreen() throws Exception {
        int w = c1 - c3;
        int h = c2 - c4;
        w = w * -1;
        h = h * -1;
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(c1, c2, w, h));
        File save_path = new File("screen1.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(img, "JPG", save_path);
        GraphicalUserInterface.getLabelIcon().setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(img).getImage().getScaledInstance(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to save your cropped Pic?");
        if(JOptionPane.YES_OPTION == 0){
            PicChanges.getCurrentLabel();
        } else {
            PicChanges.getCurrentLabel();

        }
        System.out.println("Cropped image saved successfully.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        repaint();
        c1 = arg0.getXOnScreen();
        c2 = arg0.getYOnScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        repaint();
        if (drag_status == 1) {
            c3 = arg0.getXOnScreen();
            c4 = arg0.getYOnScreen();
            try {
                this.repaint();
                draggedScreen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Issue is under construction");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        repaint();
        drag_status = 1;
        c3 = arg0.getXOnScreen();
        c4 = arg0.getYOnScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        int w = c1 - c3;
        int h = c2 - c4;
        w = w * -1;
        h = h * -1;
        if (w < 0)
            w = w * -1;
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(c1, c2, w, h);
        System.out.println("paint component");

    }
}
```

---

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage imageToCut;

    public ImagePanel() {
        Dimension size = new 
        Dimension(GraphicalUserInterface.getLabelIcon().getSize());
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(imageToCut, 0, 0, null);
        System.out.println("painted");
    }
}
```

I'm confused as I can't figure out how to invoke `paint()` method, that's why as of now, the image is cropped and correctly but the rectangle is not drawn. 
As far as I understand my `paintComponent()` method is working as I invoke ImagePanel class and add `MouseListeners` to it where the `repaint()` method is called.

To invoke the `paint()` method I need to invoke `ImageScreenShot` class but here where the issues arise.

So my question is how to invoke `paint()` method called by `repaint()` method in the `MouseListeners` of `ImageScreenShot` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but at first glance I can see that:

1. You're extending `JPanel`, that's fine, but you're overriding `paint(...)` method, you should not do that, you need to override `paintComponent(...)`
2. On your second class you're overriding `paintComponent(...)` but you're not calling

   ```
   super.paintComponent(g);
   ```

   Which, is breaking the paint chain. And probably (along with 1st point) is the cause of your error.
3. See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) (Yes), you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` and call `pack()` in your application.

Comment: Thank you for the hints and a link. getPrefferedSize() was really one of the issues I should have covered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `arg0.getComponent().repaint();` where `arg0` is the MouseEvent. It will repaint the component where the event is fired.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent--

> Returns: the Component object that originated the event, or null if
>   the object is not a Component.